# Manually create spring cloud stream bindings based on dynamic configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a requirement where one or more spring cloud stream kafka-streams bindings need to be created based on dynamic configuration. By dynamic config I mean stream bindings (input-output) will be specified run-time. Either via external property file or from database.

E.g We need to create multiple stream processors where input output topic pairs and relevant configs are provided. Then code should loop through this config create and start those bindings.

In spring cloud stream we write this in a java file

```
@StreamListener(StreamBindings.INPUT)
@SendTo(StreamBindings.OUTPUT)
public KStream<String,String> process(KStream<String,String> inputStream) {
    return inputStream
     .map( ... )
     .selectKey( ... )
     .mapValues( ... );
}
```

Where StreamBindings is like

```
public interface StreamBindings {
    String INPUT = "input-topic";
    String OUTPUT = "output-topic";

    @Input(INPUT)
    KStream<String,String> inputStream();
    @Input(OUTPUT)
    KStream<String,String> outputStream();
}
```

Now I want a piece of code to create this in run-time based on info I specified above.
Can this be done and how? And can we specify body of `process` function as an argument, like some kind of message handler?

Comment: It's not clear to me the requirements here. Please keep in mind that the `StreamListener` and `EnableBinding` mechanisms have been long deprecated and removed in the `4.0.0.` version. Please see the ref docs for more details on that.

Comment: Look at the docs and see if the new functional support accomplishes your needs. If not, please create a new GH issue in Sprig Cloud Stream with more requirements and scenarios.

Comment: No currently it doesn't. What SCS does is read it reads yml config of bindings as per functions written by me in the code or as per @StreamListener annotation. Now what I want is to tap into that mechanism itself which reads yml config and creates required Kafka consumer and producer internally.

Comment: As Soby pointed out, StreamListener is gone. You must be using some older unsupported version of SCSt. Functional support completely replaces annotation-based programming model. I don't know of a single use case where what user could do with StreamListener he/she can not do with functional approach. It's the opposite. .  what you could do with StreamListener you could do much easier using functional approach. So please upgarde.